# d3.js Saved Transition Error

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition

I am working in d3.js, making a chart object. My chart has an `update()` method that refreshes the data, using a transition to animate the change. Because I have several different objects to animate within one chart, I wanted to store the transition as a member of the Chart's prototype, then use `transition.each` wrapped around my transitions to allow all the transitions to inherit the settings of the outer one. I am using `setTimeout` to schedule updates to the chart over time, so it becomes an animation.

The chart is supposed to show the distribution of means of a skew population, as more and more means are taken. Here's a working version, where the transition is not saved as a member of the chart prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/pmwxcpz7/

Now, I try to modify the above code to store the transition during the constructor of the Chart. When I fetch the saved transition object and call `transition.each()` in the chart's `update` method, it works for the first several hundred calls, then stops working. Here's the above code, with the creation of the transition moved to the constructor: http://jsfiddle.net/whtfny15/1/

When I run the second version of the code, the chart stops animating part of the way through, and the console shows many errors saying

```
TypeError: t.__transition__[e] is undefined (d3.v3.min.js:5)
```

I have reduced the code to the minimum needed to generate the error here: http://jsfiddle.net/bw1e2vLo/1/ (note that the error shows in the console, but this script doesn't produce any visual output.)

When I run the code (in Firefox), watching the console, I get 200 errors, all of which say

```
TypeError: t.__transition__[e] is undefined (d3.v3.min.js:5)
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I would like to be able to save the transition object into my chart's prototype, so I can reuse the delay and duration settings for future animations.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't get any errors in your last fiddle on Chrome. I'm also not quite clear on what you're trying to achieve -- when you call the update function, what do you want to happen? Replace all the existing transitions with new ones?

Comment: I am just trying to save the transition object to my chart's prototype so that I can make a getter and setter to change that transition. Because I am using it to animate all the objects on the chart, one getter/setter would easily change all the transition parameters. When I call `update`, I want the chart to behave exactly like in the first fiddle, but I don't want to construct the transition within the update function.

Comment: The D3 way would be to redo the selection of the elements you want the transition to operate on and then do `.transition()` again. A transition has a state that makes saving it like this problematic -- what happens when you execute it depends on when that execution happens. In your particular case, you seem to do something after the transition has finished, which essentially means that you shouldn't be doing anything with it anymore.

Comment: Is there a D3 way to store a transition's settings so I can easily reuse them? I don't mind alternatives to storing the transition object, but I would like to have a persistent set of settings that I can apply to future transitions in my object, and I thought perhaps I could store the entire transition. As for the transition being over, consider http://jsfiddle.net/whtfny15/3/, where I simply wait 5 seconds to apply a single transition (meanCount=1). On FireFox, I get the same error most of the time. The transition seems to expire; if I wait only half a second it usually works.

Comment: Actually, I now see your point. If I construct the original transition with delay greater than 5 seconds, the time-delayed animation works, because it happens within 5 seconds of the construction of the original transition. If the original transition's lifetime is shorter than the timeout, it fails. I didn't realize the transition could only run once, but it makes sense. If you would like to make your comment an answer I'd be happy to set it as the correct response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store D3 transitions because they are stateful -- what happens when you operate on them depends on whether they are scheduled, running, or finished. If they are finished you can't in fact do a lot with them at all, as you've discovered. In general, you should only ever manipulate a transition when creating it.

The D3 way to do multiple transitions is to re-select the elements to operate on and initialise a new transition. You can store the parameters (delay and duration) in separate variables if you want to reuse them. If you're using a custom function for the transition itself, you can also save that separately and "assign" it to the transition using [`.attrTween()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#attrTween).

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add that I opened [an issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2112) for this question on the d3 GitHub, and Mr. Bostock suggested using `transition.call()` to apply the settings in a callback right before using the transition.

The code would look something like this:

```
function myTransitionSettings(transition) {
  transition
      .duration(100)
      .delay(0);
}

// Then later…
d3.transition().call(myTransitionSettings)…
```

The callback has access to the current transition object, so it can apply the same settings to each new transition that invokes it.